# Cómo sacar el id del registro con el valor más alto de un grupo

Tags: sql, group-by

estaba haciendo unas prácticas que me mandaron para clase sobre selects y me encuentro atascado en una consulta que manda lo siguiente: "Obtener el nombre, el género y la valoración de la película mejor valorada por cada género".

Para ello no hace falta más que la tabla PELÍCULAS, que tiene la siguiente estructura: `CREATE TABLE peliculas ( id bigInt, nombre varchar(250), genero varchar(250), año bigInt, valoracion float4, sinopsis varchar(250), PRIMARY KEY (id) );`

(No paso los inserts para no petar el post)

He intentado lo siguiente: `select nombre, genero, valoracion from peliculas where valoracion in ( select max(valoracion) from peliculas group by genero);`

Cuya salida por pantalla es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto no me da el resultado que quiero, puesto que hay dos películas de diferentes géneros con exactamente la misma valoración, la película que no tiene que aparecer es "Batman Begins", que tiene la misma valoración que "El lobo de Wall Street". En resumen, el resultado esperado sería este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no sé cómo obtener este resultado sin excluir manualmente a dicha película. Cualquier ayuda sería agradecida.

Answer (score 1):

Primero consideremos la siguiente estructura

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[peliculas] (
  [id] int  NOT NULL,
  [nombre] varchar(255) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS  NULL,
  [genero] varchar(255) COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AS  NULL,
  [año] int  NULL,
  [valoracion] int  NULL
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'1', N'Harry Potter', N'Aventura', N'2021', N'10')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'2', N'Vengadores', N'Aventura', N'2011', N'8')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'3', N'La vida es Bella', N'Drama', N'2021', N'9')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'4', N'La Carcel', N'Aventura', N'2001', N'10')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'5', N'Ella', N'Drama', N'2015', N'9')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'6', N'Rapidos y Furiosos', N'Accion', N'2001', N'8')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'7', N'IT', N'Terror', N'2015', N'10')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'8', N'La Sombra', N'Terror', N'2021', N'7')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'9', N'Aviones', N'Accion', N'2021', N'10')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[peliculas] ([id], [nombre], [genero], [año], [valoracion]) 
VALUES (N'10', N'Esposa Enojada', N'Terror', N'2021', N'10')
GO
```

Lo cual nos genera esta tabla, en orden de ID

[image: tabla1]

La ordenaré por genero para que se entienda mejor mi respuesta. Tengan presente el año de cada película

[image: tabla2]

Con la consulta de @Japv

```
select genero, max(valoracion) as val, max(nombre) as nombre
from peliculas
group by genero
```

El resultado es

[image: Resultado1]

Donde claramente se ve el error puesto que en el genero Acción, **Rápidos y Furiosos** tiene 8 de valoración mientras que **Aviones** tiene 10. Lo mismo con el genero Aventura donde **Vengadores** tiene 8 de valoración mientras que **Harry Potter** y **La Cárcel** ambas tienen 10 de valoración pero años diferentes. Solo tomare esos dos géneros de ejemplo.

Yo hice esta query

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT id, nombre, genero, año, valoracion, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY genero ORDER BY año DESC) rn 
FROM peliculas) P
WHERE rn = 1
```

El resultado es

[image: Resultado2]

Donde en efecto en el genero Acción aparece **Aviones** como mejor valorada, lo mismo para el genero Aventura donde **Harry Potter** se queda con el primer lugar.

Ahora bien, yo lo lleve un poco mas lejos y como en cada genero pueden haber películas con la misma valoración tomé el año de esta para coger la mas reciente y por eso es que en el genero Aventura, aunque **La Cárcel** también tiene 10 de valoración, pero al haber sido estrenada en 2001 mi script coge a **Harry Potter** que se estrenó en el año 2021.

La complejidad aumentará en cuanto mas filtros se tomen en cuenta...

Comment: Vale, te doy mi voto

Comment: Hola buenas, la verdad que no puedo decirte nada porque yo desconocía lo que eran tanto el **over()** como el **partition by** , pero después de buscarlo un rato por Internet ya me he enterado para que sirve cada función. El caso es que no sé por qué se filtran correctamente los resultados del ejercicio excepto por dos valores que, a pesar de no tener la mejor valoración de su propio género, aparecen en el resultado de la consulta. Imagino que será porque no tenemos bases de datos exactamente iguales. De todas maneras el ejercicio ya está resuelto, así que muchas gracias igualmente!!

Comment: La verdad, después de todo no se que es lo que querías obtener. Por lo menos espero que esto sirva para otros que tengan un problema similar. Tan bonita que me había quedado la respuesta :'-(

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el nombre, género y valoración de la película mejor valorada por cada género, puedes utilizar la siguiente consulta SQL:

SELECT p1.nombre, p1.genero, p1.valoracion
FROM peliculas p1
WHERE p1.valoracion = (
SELECT MAX(p2.valoracion)
FROM peliculas p2
WHERE p2.genero = p1.genero
);

Esta consulta utiliza una subconsulta para obtener la valoración máxima de cada género y luego compara esa valoración con la valoración de cada película en la tabla principal. Solo se seleccionarán las películas que tengan la valoración máxima para cada género.

Espero que esto te sea útil. Si tienes alguna otra pregunta o necesitas más ayuda, no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: Tu consulta es incorrecta, para que el operador igual funcione con tu subconsulta, está debería devolver un solo resultado y tú subconsulta devuelve varios, por lo que dará error.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funciona como yo quiero, puesto que sale por pantalla la respuesta deseada sin filtrar manualmente la película "Batman Begins", pero me parece extraño porque como dice @Japv , debería devolver más de un resultado además de no utilizar GROUP BY en ningún momento. En cualquier caso, esta era la respuesta que quería, muchas gracias por el apoyo!

Comment: @SergioEstrella, lo que pides en tu pregunta es: **Obtener el nombre, el género y la valoración de la película mejor valorada por cada género** Por eso tanto Japv como yo buscamos ese resultado, al final esta consulta como ya lo dice Japv devuelve mas resultados que uno por genero, como tu lo pides. Para otra vez deberías especificar mejor lo que quieres porque esta respuesta (aunque te sirva) no hace expresamente lo que en tu pregunta pides.